# How to use template from another context, i.e. get frontend template from backend?

Tags: symfony1

It's need for preview function in backend. I want to avoid duplicating templates.

```
// in some backend module action
$this->setTemplate(sfConfig::get('sf_apps_dir').'/frontend/modules/module/templates/tpl');
```

because context is backend, how about partials in tpl, routes and so forth?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Comment: I've found solution for partials: [CrossAppPartialView.class.php](http://github.com/wowo/crossApp/blob/master/lib/CrossAppPartialView.class.php)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use templates from other modules and even other apps.

The documented way to use a template from another module is

```
$this->setTemplate('templateName, 'moduleName');
```

There is no documented way to use a template from another application, but by looking at the source code for symfony (1.x, anyway), you find that you can set the template from another application by:

`$this->setTemplate('templateName','../../appName/modules/moduleName');`

Answer (score -1):

When you call $this->setTemplate($name), $name refers to the name of a template within **the same** module.  You cannot set templates from other modules using this method.

Comment: but it works =), if template has't partials. If it has, symfony assumes current context e. g. backend and fails